# How to fix VirtualBox that can't open since Mountain Lion upgrade?

Tags: macos, upgrade, virtualbox

I've a lot of softwares on my Mac, so, I've forgot to check some of them before upgrading MacOS to Mountain Lion (from Lion)

Since Mountain Lion, VirtualBox throw this message when I try to open it:

> You can't open the application "VirtualBox.app" because it is not supported on the type of Mac

What is the better (*not the simpler* but really the better) way to update VirtualBox without breaking anything?

Can I install the latest version over the old one?
Or must I uninstall completely the old one and reinstall it form scratch?

Or anything else?

Which are the problems I can expect?

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

[EDIT] in reply to the comment:

The VirtualBox.app details declare `version: 4.1.8`

For the Mac, it's a

**15 inch, Late 2011**

**Processor**  2.4 GHz Intel Core i7
**Memory**  8 GB 1333 MHz DDR3
**Graphics**  AMD Radeon HD 6770M 1024 MB
**Software**  OS X 10.8 (12A269)

Comment: What version of VirtualBox do you currently have? What type of Mac do you have?

Comment: @Gerry post edited with informations you need, thank you for your help

Comment: FWIW, VirtualBox 4.1.18 is the first version that specifically supports Mountain Lion.

Comment: @pmjordan compatibility was earlier than 4.1.18. https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10267 notes that **4.1.16** was made compatible with a seeded build of Mountain Lion (and that Apple permitted that version to run).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be no problems upgrading to the latest version of VirtualBox. You can just download and run the installer to upgrade, no additional uninstall steps are required.

You can also update automatically from the "VirtualBox" menu, by choosing "Check for Updates...". It should find a newer version, and prompt to download and install.

Comment: It's impossible to update automatically from VirtualBox as it can't open… But I can install the new version over the old one?

Comment: @PascalQyy, you're right, but indeed you can just download the latest version and install it over the old one.

Comment: In the past, following an update, a *saved* VirtualBoxVM was **no longer usable**. For that reason my habit is to have no VirtualBoxVM in the saved state before any update of VirtualBox. In an edge case I might suggest attention to `Exceptions.plist` https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10267#comment:5 but proceed with caution – risk of kernel panic.